# Configure Thick Client (Empower Application) Application with Openam

Tags: java, openam, forgerock

My requirement is that I have to integrate Thick client application,Non-web based application with openam.Could you guys please tell me which protocol i have to use to do this job and could you please tell me the steps i have to do for the integration.

Comment: What would you like to achieve by this integration?
Leveraging OpenAM for authentication?

Comment: yes 
I have to authenticate the User using openam

Comment: If you can change the code of the application, you can use the "Authentication APIs" of OpenAM. Please keep in mind that this will not give you "SSO" though.